# Different font size after printing form Google chrome web and iPad Web Viewer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am using one simple html file where i use Google font **droidsans** and mention font size 20px.

We use the same html template for printing from **web chrome** and **iPad app web viewer** but I am getting different font size after print.

Web Chrome print is larger than iPad web viewer.

I tried `webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` but this won't help me.

Has anyone run into similar problem/recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari both uses different rendering engines blink and webkit namely. So you may expect little difference in rendering.
On side note try to avoid webkit-* prefixed styles wherever possible as those won't be supported across browsers.